# Making this LINQ projection query better

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a domain class defined like this:

```
public class MyDomainItem
{
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
    public string PropertyB {get;set;}
    public string ItemStatus {get;set;}
    public ClassA ObjectA {get;set;}
    public ClassB ObjectB {get;set;}
}
```

And then I have a LINQ query that looks like this:

```
var mylist = from a in someList 
              join b in someOtherList on a.Id equals b.Id
              select new MyDomainItem
              {
                  PropertyA = a.SomeProperty,
                  PropertyB = b.SomeOtherProperty,
                  ObjectA = a,
                  ObjectB = b
              }
```

Based on what I know, I can resolve the `ItemStatus` by either:

```
foreach(var i in mylist)
{
    if (i.ObjectA.YetAnotherProperty == "some criteria")
    {
        if (i.ObjectA.NestedObject.NestedProperty == "price is missing")
        {
            i.ItemStatus = "bad - category 1";
        }
        else
        {
            i.ItemStatus = "bad - category 2";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        i.ItemStatus = "good";
    }
}
```

Or by calling a function, resolved in the LINQ query:

```
var mylist = from a in someList 
              join b in someOtherList on a.Id equals b.Id
              select new MyDomainItem
              {
                  PropertyA = a.SomeProperty,
                  PropertyB = b.SomeOtherProperty,
                  ObjectA = a,
                  ObjectB = b,
                  ItemStatus = ResolveStatus(a)
              }
```

Something in my mind just keep saying that there must be a better way. What I'd really love to do is something roughly like:

```
var mylist = from a in someList 
              join b in someOtherList on a.Id equals b.Id
              select new MyDomainItem
              {
                  PropertyA = a.SomeProperty,
                  PropertyB = b.SomeOtherProperty,
                  ObjectA = a,
                  ObjectB = b,
                  ItemStatus = ()=>
                  {
                      if (a.ObjectA.YetAnotherProperty == "some criteria")
                      {
                          if (a.ObjectA.NestedObject.NestedProperty == 
                              "price is missing")
                          {
                              return "bad - category 1";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              return "bad - category 2";
                          }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          return "good";
                       }
                  }
              }
```

Is there something similar to this that I can do?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why would you prefer that last version? Using a method seems the most reasonable and readable

Comment: what is `i` in your anonymous method?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, oops! thanks for the catch. i committed a copy/paste crime...! LOL

Comment: @BrokenGlass: sigh, yeah, I guess that'll be the way to go then. I just wish there was some way to inline it all. The method approach is inefficient, especially when I know that this method is in reality not truly reusable except in this one context. Makes me wish for a Pascal-style nested function, even.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this?

```
select new MyDomainItem
{
    PropertyA = a.SomeProperty,
    PropertyB = b.SomeOtherProperty,
    ObjectA = a,
    ObjectB = b,
    ItemStatus = (a.YetAnotherProperty == "some criteria")
                     ? (a.NestedObject.NestedProperty == "price is missing"
                         ? "bad - category 1"
                         : "bad - category 2")
                     : "good";
```

Although I would suggesting extending ObjectA with a property which does this evaluation for you, it doesn't look nice in the LINQ query.  If you don't have the source, you could use an extension method

```
string GetItemStatus(this ObjectA item) {
    if (item.YetAnotherProperty != "some criteria") {
        return "good";
    }
    if (item.NestedObject.NestedProperty == "price is missing") {
        return "bad - category 1";
    }
    return "bad - category 2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a MyDomainItem constructor that accepts the two properties and two objects, and sets the status? It will make MyDomainItem a more robust class (the status validity will not depend on the caller's good will), and will also solve your style problem.